# Qt Mac Application storing data path

Tags: c++, macos, qt, app-store

I ve an application that has been rejected, by inspecting it, i find that i need to write inside the application bundle (which is not clear to me yet).
I used the following code Qt 5.9.1:

```
QStandardPaths::StandardLocation type = static_cast<QStandardPaths::StandardLocation>(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
QString directory = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(type);
```

when i debug the path in qt creator, it is 
directory= "/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Myname/Myapplicaiton"

I tried the following which resulted in the same

```
QString directory = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation).first();
```

But we need to add the data inside the application bundle. As far as i understand, it should be myapplication.app\data\ (please correct me if mistaken)

What is the correct way to define the path in Qt for appstore applications?

is there a way to provide permission to write to this path ?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried using QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::ApplicationsLocation).first() + "/data"?

Comment: Changing or adding files within the application bundle will destroy the code signature - I'm not sure one wants to do this.

Comment: yes, this will destroy code signature?

Comment: i noticed that, appstore rejected the app for a crash on 12.6, however on my local machine, it does not crash. Could it be that i need some sort of entitlement to add this path ? Any body knows how to use this key or a similar key for write permission: com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write

Comment: The entitlement `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` allows you to access a file outside of your sandbox. However, that file must be actively selected by the user via an Open-/Save-Panel. Read the docs for `PowerBox`.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC try this:

```
auto path =  QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
path += "/data";
```